# Finding the maximum value of a complex-valued function

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $\phi_a(z) = \frac{a-z}{1-az}$ for $a \in \mathbb{R} ,z \in \mathbb{C}$. If $a \in [-1,1]$ and $b \in [-1,1]$, show that

$$\max |\phi_a(z)-\phi_b(z)| = 2\frac{a-b}{1-ab} \hspace{1cm} |z| \leq 1$$

*Attempt / Work.*

We compute

$$|\phi_a(z)-\phi_b(z)| = \Big| \frac{a-z}{1-az} - \frac{b-z}{1-bz} \Big|$$

$$= \Big| \frac{(a-z)(1-bz) - (b-z)(1-az)}{(1-az)(1-bz)} \Big| = \Big| \frac{[-z+bz^2+a-abz]-[-z+az^2-abz+b]}{abz^2-az-bz+1} \Big|$$

Since $a,b \in [-1,1]$, we know

$$\Big|  \frac{bz^2+a-b}{abz^2-az-bz+1}\Big| \leq \Big| \frac{z^2}{z^2-2z+1} \Big| = \Big| \frac{z^2}{(z-1)^2}\Big|$$

But I cannot figure out where to go from here. Any advice is greatly appreciated.

Comment: @Buraian Joke's on you. Check again.

Comment: I guess I had it coming :(. I concede my remark

Comment: @Buraian Check it again now lol. Also do you know how to solve the problem? I need help lmao

Comment: [This principle](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1356499/maximum-is-attained-on-the-boundary) may help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume wlog $a \ne b$ as otherwise the result is zero and then by maximum modulus it is enough to find the maximum for $|z|=1$; then $$|\phi_a(z)-\phi_b(z)|=|a-b| \Big|\frac{1-z^2}{(1-az)(1-bz)} \Big|$$

Consider now $\frac{1-z^2}{(1-az)(1-bz)} -\frac{1}{1-ab} $ and notice that a simple computation gives this as $$\frac{-(z-a)(z-b)}{(1-az)(1-bz)(1-ab)}$$

But now if $|a|, |b| \ne 1$ the expression $\frac{(z-a)(z-b)}{(1-az)(1-bz)}$ is a product of disc automorphisms (a Blaschke product) so it has absolute value one on the unit circle, while if $a= \pm 1$ and/or $b=\pm 1$ the corresponding terms cancel out in the numerator and denominator so we still get absolute value $1$ on the unit circle, hence (noting that $ab < 1$ since $a \ne b$) we get $$\Big|\frac{1-z^2}{(1-az)(1-bz)} -\frac{1}{1-ab} \Big|=\frac{1}{1-ab}$$ which clearly gives by the triangle inequality that $$|\phi_a(z)-\phi_b(z)| \le \frac{2|a-b|}{1-ab}, |z|=1 $$ (so by the maximum modulus for all $|z| \le 1$)

So it is enough to find $|z|=1, \frac{(z-a)(z-b)}{(1-az)(1-bz)}=-1$ as that implies $\frac{1-z^2}{(1-az)(1-bz)} -\frac{1}{1-ab}=\frac{1}{1-ab}$ and we are done as we attain the required maximum modulus $\frac{2|a-b|}{1-ab}$

Now if either $|a| \ne 1$ or $|b| \ne 1$ the corresponding automorphism is surjective on the unit circle (and if both $|a|, |b| \ne 1$ the product is a $2:1$ map of the unit circle into itself), so we clearly can find such $z$

If both $|a|=|b|=1$ then $a= 1, b=-1$ or the other way around and then the product is identically $-1$ so the function is constant $\pm 2$ and its absolute value is indeed $2$

Comment: Excellent solution, thank you. But how did you know to subtract $\frac{1}{1-ab}$?

Comment: The answer form strongly suggests it so was first thing I tried and it worked

Comment: Oh, that seems to make a lot of sense

Comment: If the problem would have been open ended (eg find the maximum in terms of a function in $a,b$ but that not given, after taking out $a-b$ in the first computation, I would have tried a few examples with nice numbers and see what suggests itself